# DrawingVisual.Drawing very slow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to iterate through some drawings in a prexisting application (rearchitecting is an unattractive option). The drawings are stored as DrawingVisual objects:

```
foreach (DrawingVisual visual in TheDrawings)
{
    DrawingGroup group = visual.Drawing; // this is incredibly slow

    ...
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the `DrawingVisual.Drawing` property getter is incredibly slow. Just iterating through ten thousand or so visuals (not doing anything *with* them, merely iterating) takes nearly a second, all the time spent in `DrawingVisual.Drawing`.

Digging down into the WPF source code, `DrawingVisual.Drawing` delegates to `ContainerVisual.GetDrawing`, which resolves to this expensive call in a utility class `DrawingServices`:

```
internal static DrawingGroup DrawingGroupFromRenderData(RenderData renderData)
{
  DrawingGroup drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
  DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingGroup.Open();
  DrawingDrawingContext drawingDrawingContext = drawingContext as DrawingDrawingContext;
  if (drawingDrawingContext != null)
    drawingDrawingContext.CanBeInheritanceContext = false;
  DrawingContextDrawingContextWalker drawingContextWalker = new DrawingContextDrawingContextWalker(drawingContext);
  renderData.BaseValueDrawingContextWalk((DrawingContextWalker) drawingContextWalker);
  drawingContext.Close();
  return drawingGroup;
}
```

Does anyone know a better (i.e. faster) way to iterate through the children of a DrawingVisual?